# Capturing keyboard

Tags: c#, keyboard

How can I toggle an event every time F2 is pressed by the user?

```
if(/*is pressed F2*/){
    this.Close(); 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Comment: Thank you for researching but I do not need something so complex, I need just to "listen" a key press...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a key down event like :

```
    private void form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( e.KeyCode == Keys.F2 ) 
            this.Close();
    }
```

And for getting keys when you press the key on the controls of form1 : change form1's `KeyPreview` to true on form1's `page_load` event

```
    private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use a [`MessageFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx)

Create a class that implements `IMessageFilter`

```
public class YourFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public event EventHandler F2Pressed = delegate { };

    private const Int32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg != WM_KEYDOWN)
            return false;

        if ((Keys)m.WParam==Keys.F2)
            F2Pressed(this, new EventArgs());

        return false;
    }
}
```

and register it using

```
var filter = new YourFilter();
Application.AddMessageFilter(filter);
filter.F2Pressed += YourEventHandlerHere;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest method to do this:

```
private void preferences_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e ) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2) {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work if you press `f2` on other controls on your form, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12367421/359170

Answer (score 0):

Now this is working with the focus both on the form and other elements in it (now, please mark it as answer if you agreee with me):

```
public partial class preferences : Form {
    public preferences() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }
    private void preferences_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e ) {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2) {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: victor, you asked the question so you must accept the answers. and you shouldn't answer to your question !!! . just answer to your question when the other questions are incorrect or the answer is better.